# Why are the QFrame borders being cutoff on the left and top?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

Why are the QFrame borders being cutoff on the left and top? If I set the LineWidth larger the borders will show up. It appears that just a small amount is cut off.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("pyQt6 Testing")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 120)

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addStretch(1)

        self.sub = Sub("this is left and really much wider than right will ever be and is still needs to be longer", self)

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.sub)
        self.hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(Sub("this is right", self))
        self.hbox.addStretch(1)

        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)


class Sub(QtWidgets.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.Box)
        self.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Plain)
        self.setLineWidth(1)
        self.setMidLineWidth(1)

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.vbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text))
        self.vbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text))
        self.vbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text))
        self.vbox.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton(text))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I added a QVboxLayout and some stretch before, in between and at the end of the QVboxLayout and QHboxLayouts. It now shows all the borders at times while stretching the window.

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Qt5 and Linux, so it could be an issue with Qt6 and/or windows. Does changing the frame shape/shadow and line values give different results?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Qt5 and Windows.

Comment: I figured it out. It's happening because I have 125% scaling in windows for a display resolution of 2560 x 1440.